# IE7 Dynamic Menu and Whitespace

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm developing a small script which transforms formatted HTML into dynamic menus. This is being done to allow form writers to create dynamic menus without knowing much JavaScript.  The idea is that they'll just write semantic markup and the javascript code will make the menu for them.

You can see demo in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKCuw/2/).

Basically, it takes HTML that looks like this:

```
<ul data-menu-horizontal="true" data-menu-width="500px">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Code</a></li>
   <li>
      <ul data-menu-horizontal="true" datamenu-header="Sub-Menu 1" data-menu-width="500px">
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">Computer Blog</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">More News</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>     
   <li>
      <ul data-menu-vertical="true" data-menu-header="Sub-Menu 2" data-menu-width="500px">
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">Computer Blog</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">More News</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

... and transforms it into this:

```
<ul id="13575820577141" class="menu-horizontal" style="width: 500px;">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Code</a></li>
   <li>
          <h2 class="menu-horizontal-header">Sub-Menu 1</h2>
      <ul id="13575820577142" class="menu-horizontal" style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 500px;">
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">Computer Blog</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">More News</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>     
   <li>
      <h2 class="menu-vertical-header">Sub-Menu 2</h2>
      <ul id="13575820577143" class="menu-vertical" style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 500px;">
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">Computer Blog</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">More News</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

There is jQuery (starting in the `makeMenus()` function) which assigns show/hide functionality to each menu `ul` and menu header (marked as `h2`) mouseover/mouseout that shows/hides the appropriate sub-menu.

The show/hide functionality works great in all browsers that I've tested so far.  The problem is that in IE7, the "mouseover" functionality breaks whenever it hits any whitespace, even between `li` elements.  I don't want to simply remove all extra whitespace because some whitespace will be needed to "prettify" the menu.

Comment: I would not bother with IE 7.  It's old.  It came out in 2006.  Check your site's browser statistics for that version.  I bet you are not getting much traffic from that version.  I typically try to support the current version and 2 versions back.  For IE that means current = IE10 and 2 versions back = IE9 and IE8.

Comment: In 2011 IE 7 was used in world by 4% of people ([source](http://theie7countdown.com/)). As @Miguel-F mentioned, the best is to support current + 2 versions back. So, you do not need IE 7! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my corporate intranet uses IE7.  They're upgrading soon of course, but it still means lots and lots of clients that use IE7.

Comment: Please elaborate on this: "some whitespace will be needed to 'prettify' the menu"

Comment: @Nick:  I mean that some margin and/or padding will be needed to make the menu look visually appealing.  Right now, if IE7 encounters any white space, it hides the menu instead of continuing to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah... you'll never guess what the problem was.  I needed to set a background color on the 'ul' elements.  I guess that IE7 doesn't consider a transparent background as part of the element's box, at least as far as mouse-overs are concerned.  Now I'm forced to choose explicit background colors for my menu elements.  What a drag!

Thanks to anyone who took a look.  Hopefully this can help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Does using `overflow: auto;` instead of providing a background color work?